# PUT request using `UrlFetchApp` returns 'Bad Request' but the same request outside Google Apps Script works

Tags: http, curl, https, google-apps-script

This is the Google Apps Script that makes the request:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://user:password@sitename.com/api', {
  method: 'put',
  headers: { 'Accept': '*/*' },
  payload: 'foo=bar&baz=qux'
});
```

Which can be successfully posted to http://requestb.in/, for examination:

```
PUT /1bfk94g1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GoogleDocs; script; +http://docs.google.com)
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 43
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: */*

foo=bar&baz=qux
```

But fails when the request URL is `https://user:password@sitename.com/api`. The only error information shown is `Bad request: https://user:password@sitename.com/api`.

I've constructed a `curl` command which yields the exact same HTTP request:

```
curl -XPUT \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
     --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; GoogleDocs; script; +http://docs.google.com)' \
     -d foo='bar' \
     -d baz='qux'\
     https://user:password@sitename.com/api
```

Which successfully posts to `https://user:password@sitename.com/api`. How can two identical requests have different outcomes? Am I missing something with regards to my Google Apps Script? I've tried using the debugger, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `UrlFetchApp` doesn't yet support requests with credentials in the URL. The `Authorization` HTTP header needs to be built manually. The following works:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://sitename.com/api', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + password)
  }
});
```